# calculating percentage error by comparing two arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have some data in two numpy arrays.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
b = [1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7]
```

I say array `a` is my calculated result and array `b` are the true result values. I want to calculate the error percentage in my result.
Now I can loop through the two arrays and compare them `0` if the values match and `1` for a mismatch then add them up, divide by the total values and calculate percentage error.

Is there any possible faster and elegant method for doing this ?

Comment: Any approach would look at all values in both arrays right?

Comment: You probably need to give more information about what this is used for. Your algorithm gives the number of elements that mismatch. Maybe you want absolute value of mismatchs (then maybe use RMS). Or you could try using correlation. But which makes sense depends on what you are using the error value for.

Comment: Yes you're right.I probably  could get delete the word 'faster' from my post.

Comment: This is a classification problem. So I only need to know the number of misclassified values.

Answer (score 28):

First calculate the positions where `a` and `b` differ using `a != b`, then find the mean of those values:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
>>> b = np.array([1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7])
>>> error = np.mean( a != b )
>>> error
0.14285714285714285
```

Comment: OP has different `b`, probably it's worth repacing your sample with it (and to get not zero error)

Answer (score 4):

Something along the lines of:

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7])
>>> b = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
>>> (a != b).sum()/float(a.size)
0.14285714285714285
```

**Update** I'm courious why this one is *slightly* faster:

```
a = np.random.randint(4, size=1000)
b = np.random.randint(4, size=1000)
timeit('from __main__ import a, b; (a != b).sum()/float(a.size)', number=10000)
# 0.42409151163039496
timeit('from __main__ import a, b, np; np.mean(a != b)', number=10000)
# 0.5342614773662717
```

Comment: `==` should be replaced with `!=` because OP want error percentage.

Comment: `np.mean` cast `a!=b` as `dtype = np.double` for the accumulate operation which takes slightly longer then when you simply sum `(a != b).sum()` as `np.int`. Time `(a != b).sum(dtype=np.double)/float(a.size)` and `np.mean(a != b, dtype=np.int)` for an example.